# Can't get on "Go to Meeting" webinar

Tags: networking

I just had Ubuntu installed on my computer. Tonight when I went to go on a webinar with "Go to Meeting", it wouldn't let me on, saying that web browser would not support it. When I went to the requirements, it said I needed Windows or Mac.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2):

GotoMeeting doesn't support Linux: http://www1.gotomeeting.com/default/help/g2m/tips_for_success/faqs.htm#15maclinux

You could find another solution to do meetings, or virtualize a Windows/Mac machine.

Answer (score 1):

There are several others that do supprt Linux. You can see my article on this topic here: http://linuxpcplus.com/week-5-webmeeting-and-webinars-with-linux/

In it I give several options.
However, I am guessing that the host of the webinar you wish to attend is using GoToMeeting, which would mean you have to use it as well. You may be able to use spice's suggestion. If not, try using a virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FireFox, you could always spoof your user agent using [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), or [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) for Chrome/Chromium. If they use their own proprietary embedded web object, you'll be out of luck, unless you run a browser in Wine.